# Codeigniter: "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters" when submitting a form

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, input

So I have a simple form with some inputs in my codeigniter project:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="new_project" value="true"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre"/><br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Cliente" name="cliente"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="crear"/>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I get the following message:

> ```
> An Error Was Encountered
> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
> ```

and in the address bar of my browser, the following appears:

> http://mycodeigniterproject/index.php/projects/manage%20%3E%3Cinput%20type=

I already tried modifying this in my config.php file:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=a-z 0-9?~%.,:_\-';
```

and

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Thanks for your attention

Comment: DO NOT USE <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>. This is a security vulnerability. https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/php-server-vars-not-safe-in-forms-or-links/

Comment: you can debug `system/core/URI.php`  `_filter_uri` function.why it's going inside if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I feel pretty stupid now. I was trying to submit a file without the multipart :S

here is the corrected code:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('projects/manage?pid='.$project->id);?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="crear"/>
</form>
```